# Can't click on my navigation links

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, href

Hello I'm a beginner and got a problem with my navigationbar in HTML. I've tried a lot but they are still unclickable...

Is there a mistake in my HTML?

```
<header>
<nav display: inline;>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <navi><img src="images/header_logo.png" alt="Logo" href="index.html" width="40%" height="40%" /></navi>
        </li>
        <li>
            <navi>
                <z class="active" href="index.html">Startseite</z>
            </navi>
        </li>
        <li>
            <navi>
                <z href="produkte.html">Produkte</z>
            </navi>
        </li>
        <li>
            <navi>
                <z href="about.html">Über uns</z>
            </navi>
        </li>
        <li>
            <navi>
                <z href="agb.html">AGB</z>
            </navi>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

or is the mistake in my CSS? It's probably not the best way to style it but it looks good in my eyes. However I cant click any links...

```
body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

img {
max-width: 100%;
}

ul {
margin: 0px;
list-style: none;
padding: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: burlywood;
}

li navi {
float: left;
display: block;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
}

li navi z {
float: left;
display: block;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 30px;
margin-top: 40px;
color: white;
border: 2px solid white;
}

.active {
background-color: #deae6f;
}

li z:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #deb27a;
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: structure of html <li> <a href="">Menu One</a> </li> why you are using <navi> <a href=""></a></navi>

Comment: use <a> instead of <navi> tag.

Comment: and <nav style="display:inline;"> [ https://jsfiddle.net/q2rk5p5L/ ]

Comment: Please read about [minimal examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Shaving the code down to the smallest example that causes the error not only saves time for other users, but will often reveal the problem to you before you even ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've a problem in your code, styles, anchors are not correct there is the correct code below.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;

}

img {
max-width: 100%;
}

ul {
margin: 0px;
list-style: none;
padding: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: burlywood;
}

li nav {
float: left;
display: block;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
}

li a {
float: left;
display: block;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 30px;
margin-top: 40px;
color: white;
border: 2px solid white;
}

.active {
background-color: #deae6f;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #deb27a;
}
```

```html
<header>
<nav style="display: block;">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <nav><img src="images/header_logo.png" alt="Logo" href="index.html" width="40%" height="40%" /></nav>
        </li>
        <li>
            <nav>
                <a class="active" href="index.html">Startseite</a>
            </nav>
        </li>
        <li>
            <nav>
                <a href="produkte.html">Produkte</a>
            </nav>
        </li>
        <li>
            <nav>
                <a href="about.html">Über uns</a>
            </nav>
        </li>
        <li>
            <nav>
                <a href="agb.html">AGB</a>
            </nav>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Yonas. I can finally move on. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the link for Your above Problem https://jsfiddle.net/kj0w9g76/
Reason:- for anchor tag we use 'a' not with 'z'
instead of navi tag we use nav tag as used in code below.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: burlywood;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

li nav {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

li nav z {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 30px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.active {
  background-color: #deae6f;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #deb27a;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav style="display: inline;">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <nav><a href="index.html" width="40%" height="40%" ><img src="images/header_logo.png" alt="Logo"/></a></navi>
      </li>
      <li>
        <nav>
          <a class="active" href="index.html">Startseite</a>
        </nav>
      </li>
      <li>
        <nav>
          <a href="produkte.html">Produkte</a>
        </nav>
      </li>
      <li>
        <nav>
          <a href="about.html">Über uns</a>
        </nav>
      </li>
      <li>
        <nav>
          <a href="agb.html">AGB</a>
        </nav>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```